# Wifi "device not ready"

Tags: wireless, 16.04, hp-pavilion

When Ubuntu starts, at first it shows the wifi connections nearby and tries to connect without success. As it tries, it seems that the range that it sees wifi connections gets shorter until it doesn't see anything and fails to connect. When I click on the wifi icon, it says "device not ready" below "Wi-Fi".

When I run `sudo service NetworkManager status` it returns errors saying that it tried 5 times without success: "supplicant interface keeps failing, giving up".

Output from `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`:

```
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 [8086:08b3] (rev 83)
    DeviceName: Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 3160 802.11ac 1x1 WiFi + BT 4.0 Combo Adapter`
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 3160 [8086:0070]
```

Others command's outputs:

```
$ sudo service NetworkManager status
● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Ter 2016-09-06 14:55:25 BRT; 9min ago
Main PID: 26058 (NetworkManager)
CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
        ├─26058 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon
        ├─26077 /sbin/dhclient -d -q -sf /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper -pf /var/run/dhclient-eno1.pid -lf /var/lib/NetworkManager/dh
        └─/usr/sbin/dnsmasq --no-resolv --keep-in-foreground --no-hosts --bind-interfaces --pid-file=/var/run/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.pid --listen-address=127.0.1.1 --cache-size=0 --proxy-dnssec --enable-dbus=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq --conf-dir=/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d

Set 06 14:56:52 jpbraga NetworkManager[26058]: <warn>  [1473184612.4170] device (wlo1): re-acquiring supplicant interface (#3).
Set 06 14:57:08 jpbraga NetworkManager[26058]: <error> [1473184628.3652] sup-iface[0x27aa8c0,wlo1]: error adding interface: wpa_supplicant couldn't grab this interface.
Set 06 14:57:08 jpbraga NetworkManager[26058]: <info>  [1473184628.3652] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: starting -> down
Set 06 14:57:18 jpbraga NetworkManager[26058]: <warn>  [1473184638.4194] device (wlo1): re-acquiring supplicant interface (#4).
Set 06 14:57:34 jpbraga NetworkManager[26058]: <error> [1473184654.3567] sup-iface[0x27aaa20,wlo1]: error adding interface: wpa_supplicant couldn't grab this interface.
Set 06 14:57:34 jpbraga NetworkManager[26058]: <info>  [1473184654.3568] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: starting -> down
Set 06 14:57:44 jpbraga NetworkManager[26058]: <warn>  [1473184664.4200] device (wlo1): re-acquiring supplicant interface (#5).
Set 06 14:58:00 jpbraga NetworkManager[26058]: <error> [1473184680.3670] sup-iface[0x2769400,wlo1]: error adding interface: wpa_supplicant couldn't grab this interface.
Set 06 14:58:00 jpbraga NetworkManager[26058]: <info>  [1473184680.3671] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: starting -> down
Set 06 14:58:00 jpbraga NetworkManager[26058]: <info>  [1473184680.3671] device (wlo1): supplicant interface keeps failing, giving up
```

I tried to install wicd but it also doesn't work.

```
$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlo1      IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:off/any  `
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=22 dBm
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off`
          Power Management:on`

eno1      no wireless extensions.
```

I saw some posts that I believe are not entirely equal to mine, so I don't know how to proceed.

Laptop: HP Pavilion 14-V066BR

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Sorry the delay, The laptop is not mine and I don't have it with me. Tomorrow I'll be able to run the suggested command.
Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Sorry again the delay. Only now that I could come back to the problem.
I guess that when there is a line break in the code, the formating tool don't get it. I pasted it directly from the terminal

Comment: To format the text properly use `{}` button.